# Python script can't find file anymore after packing with pyarmor/pyinstaller as unix executable on Mac

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyarmor

My problem is that when I pack my .py script with either pyarmor or pyinstaller the script can't find my files anymore. I am using this code to read a file:

```
with open('./file.txt', "r") as textfile:
            textdata = textfile.read()
print(textdata)
```

I found out that the script uses `/Users/{username}` as absolute file path which is my problem. Because no matter where the file is started it always uses this `/Users/{username}` path. I even tried getting the file path with:

`workingpath = str(Path().absolute())`

But even that returns `/Users/{username}`. Is there any solution to this problem?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Without access to (that part of) your script and the layout of the data files it needs, how can we tell you anything more? The code you show simply looks in the the invoking user's current working directory.

Comment: Sorry, I noticed that I forgot to add it. I edited the question.

Comment: Again, nothing in the code you show examines an absolute path, and it's unclear which part of that (if any) you replaced with an absolute path, or why you thought that would help.

Comment: I'm very new to python so sorry for any mistakes. I thought that with "./" it defines the "working directory". So it should read the file if it's in the same folder as the executable. I did only print this `workingpath = str(Path().absolute())` command. And than saw that the path is `/Users/{username}`.

Comment: `.` is indeed the current working directory; that's why `./file.txt` looks for a file in the current directory. A common beginner mistake is assuming that it's the _script's_ directory but it's not; it's the current user's. If you start with a relative file name and run `absolute()` on it nothing really changes; you are still referring to the same file.

Comment: Quick googling suggests adding a `--add-data` option to pyinstaller but I'm not familiar enough with pyinstaller to tell you anything more, and your question still doesn't explain what file you are trying to access or how it's supposed to be provided.